# How to convert JavaScript Unicode range regex into PHP PCRE?

Tags: javascript, regex, pcre

I have this regex range for Latin being used in JavaScript

```
[\u0000-\u007F]
```

and want to convert it into PHP PCRE but it tells me **\u This token is not supported** while I just want to use the range of Unicodes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PCRE does not support the `\uFFFF` syntax instead it uses `\x{FFFF}`. For example:

```
[\x{0000}-\x{007F}]
```

Comment: i tried to apply this on this regex here **[\x{00A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}]** from another question and got a this **Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: range out of order in character class** is there a reason for this?

Comment: @JoeDoe - you probably need to add the `u` modifier to your regex pattern for it to work with PHP PCRE. For example, `/[\x{00A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}]/u`